# Grisu not defined - Julia

Tags: plot, julia

I have just started to use Julia a few days back.
While trying to plot, I am getting the following error:

```
using Plots
x = 1:10; y = rand(10); # These are the plotting data
plot(x, y)
```

ERROR:

```
UndefVarError: Grisu not defined

Stacktrace:
  [1] getproperty
    @ .\Base.jl:26 [inlined]
  [2] plain_precision_heuristic(xs::Vector{Float64})
    @ Showoff C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Showoff\RaPxi\src\Showoff.jl:84
  [3] showoff(xs::Vector{Float64}, style::Symbol)
    @ Showoff C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Showoff\RaPxi\src\Showoff.jl:117
  [4] optimal_ticks_and_labels(sp::Plots.Subplot{Plots.GRBackend}, axis::Plots.Axis, ticks::Nothing)
    @ Plots C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Plots\5srrj\src\axes.jl:187
  [5] optimal_ticks_and_labels
    @ C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Plots\5srrj\src\axes.jl:128 [inlined]
  [6] get_ticks(sp::Plots.Subplot{Plots.GRBackend}, axis::Plots.Axis)
    @ Plots C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Plots\5srrj\src\axes.jl:238
  [7] _update_min_padding!(sp::Plots.Subplot{Plots.GRBackend})
    @ Plots C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Plots\5srrj\src\backends\gr.jl:890
  [8] iterate
    @ .\generator.jl:47 [inlined]
  [9] _collect(c::Matrix{AbstractLayout}, itr::Base.Generator{Matrix{AbstractLayout}, 
typeof(Plots._update_min_padding!)}, #unused#::Base.EltypeUnknown, isz::Base.HasShape{2})
    @ Base .\array.jl:691
 [10] collect_similar
    @ .\array.jl:606 [inlined]
 [11] map
    @ .\abstractarray.jl:2294 [inlined]
 [12] _update_min_padding!(layout::Plots.GridLayout)
    @ Plots C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Plots\5srrj\src\layouts.jl:310
 [13] prepare_output(plt::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend})
    @ Plots C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Plots\5srrj\src\plot.jl:184
 [14] show(io::Base64.Base64EncodePipe, m::MIME{Symbol("image/png")}, 
plt::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend})
    @ Plots C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Plots\5srrj\src\output.jl:214
 [15] base64encode(::Function, ::MIME{Symbol("image/png")}, ::Vararg{Any, N} where N; 
context::Nothing)
    @ Base64 
C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Base64\src\encode.jl:209
 [16] base64encode
    @ C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Base64\src\encode.jl:206 
[inlined]
 [17] _ijulia_display_dict(plt::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend})
    @ Plots C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Plots\5srrj\src\ijulia.jl:50
 [18] display_dict(plt::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend})
    @ Plots C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Plots\5srrj\src\init.jl:81
 [19] #invokelatest#2
    @ .\essentials.jl:708 [inlined]
 [20] invokelatest
    @ .\essentials.jl:706 [inlined]
 [21] execute_request(socket::ZMQ.Socket, msg::IJulia.Msg)
    @ IJulia C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\IJulia\e8kqU\src\execute_request.jl:112
 [22] #invokelatest#2
    @ .\essentials.jl:708 [inlined]
 [23] invokelatest
    @ .\essentials.jl:706 [inlined]
 [24] eventloop(socket::ZMQ.Socket)
    @ IJulia C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\IJulia\e8kqU\src\eventloop.jl:8
 [25] (::IJulia.var"#15#18")()
    @ IJulia .\task.jl:411
```

Googles it for a few hours. Saw some similar queries but couldn't find a satisfactory solution. Have got both Plot and Grisu packages installed.

Comment: I don't think you need to install Grisu yourself. Which version of Julia and Plots.jl are you using?

Comment: Grisu was the library used to print floats, but has been replaced by Ryu in more recent versions. To there's something wrong with versions/updates.

Comment: There was some issue in the version of the plots package. Reinstalling and getting package from REPL worked. Thanks!

Comment: I'm also getting this problem when using an old version of CSV .

Answer (score 1):

Following up on some of the conversation in the comments, the correct steps to resolve this would be:

```
# Type "]" to enter the package manager and then 

remove plots

add plots
```

which should resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

apparently Grisu was removed from Julia base after Julia 1.6. However, some older packages might still refer to it, so you need to add the now stand-alone Grisu package if you need to use older package versions.

https://juliahub.com/ui/Packages/Grisu/T2ZVU

```
Pkg.add("Grisu")

if isdefined(Base, :Grisu)
    import Base.Grisu
else
    import Grisu
end
```